# Как определить половину элементов из цикла foreach?

Tags: php, smarty

Всем привет

Есть итерация по элементам :

```
    <ul>
        {foreach from=$item.confessions.items item=confession}
            <li>{$confession.content}</li>
        {/foreach}
                    </ul>
```

Как можно определить , когда вывелась половина элементов `li`?
На половине нужно будет закрыть тег `ul` и открыть новый с другой половиной `li`

Спасибо

Comment: А зачем вам понадобилось "рвать" список пополам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
<ul>
    {foreach from=$item.confessions.items item=confession name=confession}
        <li>{$confession.content}</li>
        {if $smarty.foreach.confession.index == floor($smarty.foreach.confession.total / 2) }
</ul><ul>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

Можно еще попробовать условие (smarty2 под рукой нету, проверить не могу)

```
$smarty.foreach.confession.index == $smarty.foreach.confession.total >> 1
```

В smarty3 это было бы так:

```
<ul>
    {foreach $item.confessions.items as $confession}
        <li>{$confession.content}</li>
        {if $confession@index == $confession@total >> 1}
</ul><ul>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

Comment: Эх, в Смарти я валенок

Попробую разобраться

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов Еще забыл написать. В `{foreach}` нужно добавить `name=confession`. Дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!) Надеюсь, впредь со смарти работать я не буду)

Answer (score 5):

```css
ul {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
  <li>Не надо :)
</ul>
```

Comment: Мыслите наперед? :)

Comment: Вот именно поэтому я и спросил зачем нужно рвать список :)